# Jetpack Compose equivalent for @tools:sample/* resources

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In View system we can use `@tools:sample/*` to show placeholder data.

Example:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />
```

Using this Android Studio will display a random sample image for us to preview.

My question is, how do we achieve this in Compose?

Comment: It is not the same, but you can use the @PreviewParameter

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Are there pre supplied assets we can use? Some custom modules don't have the assets needed...